# How to loosen a stuck zip?

Tags: clothing

I have a zip stuck on my coat and neither the zipper or the teeth will move. I have tried pulling it really hard but it won’t barge.

Is there anyway to loosen the zip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Stuck fabric**

First of all check for stuck fabric behind the zip, this is a common problem and simply pulling it out should do the job.

Example:

[image: stuck fabric]

([Image Credit)](https://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Stuck-Zipper)

**Using a lubricant**

You can put a few drops of a lubricant (lip balm/Vaseline/shampoo or any other smooth substance) onto one of these cotton swabs/cotton buds:

[image: cotton swab/bud]

([Image Credit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_swab#/media/File:White_menbo.jpg)

You can then lubricate the zipper and it hopefully it won’t be stuck anymore.

Comment: It can help by pulling the zip in the reverse direction, teasing the fabric away from the zip guide.